# Polynomial product function

Tags: f#, polynomials

I'm an F# beginner trying to create a function mul to multiply two polynomials. I'm using three helper functions: add, mulX and mulC which respectively add polynomials, multiply by x and multiply by constant. The idea is that I'm representing my polynomials in lists, so [1;2;3] would be 1+2*x+3*x^2.

I've gotten the following definition as a
[guideline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8cPA.png) for combining the helper functions.

However, I can't seem to get it to work, even though (I think) I've followed the guideline completely.

I've added a screenshot of the code, helper functions and output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbkJs.png).
I get 2+7*x+13*x^2+11*x^3+3*x^4, and I'm supposed to get 2+7*x+12*x^2+10*x^3+2*x^4+3*x^5.

I'm sorry if the format is bad, this is my first post.

Where did I go wrong? I've tested my helper functions, and they seem to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you add your code directly to the question as text (instead of as a screenshot)? That makes it easier for us to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code, I think it's implemented correctly. You've just misrepresented the test. It should be:

```
mul [2;3;0;1] [1;2;3]
```

Note that the last term of the first polynomial is x<sup>3</sup>, and there's no x<sup>2</sup> term:

2 + 3x + x<sup>3</sup> = 2 + 3x + 0x<sup>2</sup> + 1x<sup>3</sup>

An easy mistake to make.